# installing packages with renv

Tags: r, install.packages, renv

I open RStudio and type

```
install.packages('rJava')
```

and it works fine.

Then I load package which has `renv` initialized and try the same command and it returns:

```
Error: package 'rJava' is not available
In addition: Warning messages:
1: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 
2: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 
>
```

What might be the reason?

**Update**

I decided to try something radical:

`remove.packages('renv')`

it and worked

but then I restarted R sessions and got back

```
# Bootstrapping renv 0.13.1 --------------------------------------------------
* Downloading renv 0.13.1 ... OK
* Installing renv 0.13.1 ... Done!
* Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.13.1.
```

Is there way to get rid of `renv`?

Another update:

I was able to deactivate renv with `renv::deactive()`

Comment: Do you mean you load a *project* that has renv initialized, not a *package*? Check that you have rJava in renv's lockfile with the version you know works

Comment: @camille, will do, but in my project with renv initialized I cannot install any packages. `install.packages('dplyr')` also failed

Comment: @user1700890 I'd suggest updating your question title to reflect that - "Can't install packages or remove renv" - it's a much more descriptive title than "Interesting issue"

Comment: @user1700890 I think you can 'get rid of' the `renv` initialisation by getting rid of the call to `source(renv/activate.R)` inside your `.Rprofile` script.

Comment: This is further documented at https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html#uninstalling-renv.

Comment: FWIW I got similar error messages as from your first problem when running `renv::install` commands and fixed it by adding `RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD=libcurl` to `.Renviron`. Suggested by this GH issue: https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/735.